# WSO2 Identity Server users and roles management page shows blank

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I just downloaded and install the WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 in CentoOS 7 to play with it.
 I created a `JDBC DataStore` instead of the `H2 datastore` that comes by default, also uncommented as default primary `User Store` the `JDBC User Store`, then run the Identity Server.
 When I go to the `management/configuration/ users and roles/users or roles`, the content area appears blank for both cases, users and roles.

So I must be doing something wrong or what? 
I am login with the default credentials of `admin/admin` that the documentation says. The documentation also says that the user must be admin in order to manage users and roles, and I hope is the case as the links to manage users and roles appears but are not working, also in the console shows no error regarding this blank page.

Any directions on what I should go? 
I can post the configuration I am using also, but is a very basic one, following the administration stated in the online documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem, i was using Java 1.8, and saw an error compiling a JSP in the logs in the console in linux, so switch to Java 1.7 and now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity server does not support Java 8.